# Can aria-label replace adding labels for all HTML inputs?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, wai-aria

I noticed that within the Bootstrap documentation, in the inline forms part it states ( http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline ):

> Screen readers will have trouble with your forms if you don't include a label for every input.

However, I noticed that there is a `aria-label` attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label which does the same.

Does this mean I can use that directly on the input instead of having to add an extra element to each input?

I am wondering if there is something specific and special about adding the labels explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `aria-` attributes in general have limited support: they are supported by assistive software and specialized browsers, whereas all mainstream browsers support the `label` element. If you only use the `aria-label` attribute and no normally visible label, then the vast majority of users see no label.

The `aria-label` attribute is intended for very special cases, typically cases where users can normally understand the meaning of a control from the page context so that a visible label is not needed, and perhaps not even desired, but people using e.g. speech browsers need an “accessible label”.

Comment: Hang on the second part of that confuses me a bit, so say this is a search input at the top of the page, it doesn't need a label and can be deciphered by context would a hidden label still be required?

Comment: @Sammaye, whether it needs a visible label is debatable (and depends on context and users), but in any case, if no visible label is present, then, by accessibility rules, `aria-label` *must* be used.